# \indexsetup and intoc from imakeidx package problem

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

I'm writing a little documentation in which I'll use some indexes per section, everything is OK using the default options of the `imakeidx` package, but, when trying to use `\indexsetup` things don't work as I wish. This is my MWE (it's data taken from other posts but it exemplifies the problem)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mydotfill.ist}
delim_0 "\\nobreak\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% \indexsetup{level=\section,toclevel=section}
\makeindex[options={-s mydotfill.ist},intoc,name=person,title={Index of persons}]
\makeindex[options={-s mydotfill.ist},intoc]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\lipsum[1]
Einstein\index[person]{Einstein}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Second}
Heisenberg\index[person]{Heisenberg} % Person index
\lipsum[3]
\index{foo}
\index{bar}
\lipsum[4]
\indexprologue{\small In this index you’ll find only
famous people’s names}
\printindex[person]
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The index and table of contents generated are correct, but when using `\indexsetup` the output is:
[image: output]

I tried to do it using the `noautomatic` option and running `makeindex` manually, but the result is the same and I have to compile three times (instead of two).

If the question is duplicated I would appreciate the link to it (I have searched a long time in the forum and have not found the answer).

Minor (related) questions: *Is it necessary for `imakeidx` to run `makeindex` every time it is compiled?* ... or would it be sufficient to run makeindex on the first build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you do `level=\section`, which makes `\section{\indexname}` at the beginning of the index (which adds a ToC entry), and then you do `intoc,toclevel=section`, which adds a `section` ToC entry for the index. Then you get what you get :-)

You should use only one of the two. If you want *numbered* index sections, then just use `level=\section`:

```
\indexsetup{level=\section}
\makeindex[options={-s mydotfill.ist},name=person,title={Index of persons}]
\makeindex[options={-s mydotfill.ist}]
```

then the indexes will already start with `\section`, and LaTeX will do the right thing. The output looks like:

> [image]

And if you want *unnumbered* sections for the indexes, then you have to explicitly ask for `intoc` and tell `imakeidx` to make a `section`-level ToC entry:

```
\indexsetup{toclevel=section}
\makeindex[options={-s mydotfill.ist},intoc,name=person,title={Index of persons}]
\makeindex[options={-s mydotfill.ist},intoc]
```

(here `level=\section*` is the default). The output will look like:

> [image]

---

Minor (related) answers: It's not strictly *necessary* to run `makeindex` in every run. You just need a `makeindex` run when you add/remove/change an index entry. But for `imakeidx` to *detect* that it would either require `-shell-escape` (and something like `md5sum` or whatnot) or it would need to manually check for every index entry, which would probably be more time- and memory-consuming than running `makeindex` every time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and clarification from `makeindex`, seeing your answer I feel a little silly, when I checked the documentation I didn't realize that the two options were disjointed :)